# How to copy from a database to a text file using VBScript?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, vbscript, filestream

I have an example in C# code, but it is using `streamWriter`. It must be involving with `FileSystemObject` rite. If yes, what are methods should I use?  I want to code using VBScript [WSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host), and my database is MS [SQL Server 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2005).

Any solution, references, or guide are helpful.

```
using (StreamWriter tw = File.AppendText("c:\\INMS.txt"))
{
    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        tw.WriteLine("id, ip address, message, datetime");
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            tw.Write(reader["id"].ToString());
            tw.Write(", " + reader["ip"].ToString());
            tw.Write(", " + reader["msg"].ToString());
            tw.WriteLine(", " + reader["date"].ToString());
        }
        tw.WriteLine("Report Generate at : " + DateTime.Now);
        tw.WriteLine("---------------------------------");
        tw.Close();
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: what you want exactly? do you want us to convert this script to vb or you need an equivalent to it?

Comment: i want it in VBScript. The c# codes is example on what i want. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Mitch: Tried to undo the downvote but you were a bit quick for me.  Not all of us can spend every waking minute watching all that is happening on SO.  Lighten up and slow down bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VBScript you need ADODB objects and the `FileSystemObject` from the `Scripting` library.  Something akin to:-

```
Dim conn: Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open "an ole DB mysql connection string", usernameIfneeded, passwordIfNeeded

Dim cmd : Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandText = "your SQL code here"
cmd.CommantType = 1 ''# adCmdText Command text is a SQL query

Dim rs : Set rs = cmd.Execute

Dim fs : Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim textStream : Set textStream = fs.OpenTextFile("c:\inms.txt", 8, True)
textStream.WriteLine "id, ip address, message, datetime"
Do Until rs.EOF

   textStream.Write rs("id") & "," 
   textStream.Write rs("ip") & "," 
   textStream.Write rs("msg") & "," 
   textStream.WriteLine rs("date")   

  rs.MoveNext
Loop

textStream.Close
rs.Close
conn.Close
```

Comment: Tqvm for the solution, but after close, no need to set both rs and conn  = Nothing ? And all sql command must use and set to ADODB.Command?

Comment: Ordinarily this sort of code should be compartmentalised into functions.  As local variable rs and conn will pass out of scope and be released as the function exits.  I personally don't like adding unnecessary set to nothings but some people seem get a warm fuzzy comforting feeling doing so.